# Should I create my AsyncCallback as a new object and is EndInvoke optional?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am trying to use asynchronous calls to save a database and I have realised my understanding of how things work may be incorrect. I have done a number of google searches but it hasn't helped to reduce my confusion

What I have is similar to the following:

```
private delegate bool MyDelegate();

private void ExportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Disable button
    exportButton.Enabled = false;

    MyDelegate deleg = ExportDatabase;

    // Begin the export
    deleg.BeginInvoke(ExportDatabaseCallback, null);
}

public bool ExportDatabase()
{
    // Do Stuff
    return true;
}

private void ExportDatabaseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Enable button
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { exportButton.Enabled = true; });

    MessageBox.Show("Exporting Database complete");
}
```

Now, looking at other pages seems to indicate in my BeginInvoke I should do this as: `deleg.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(ExportDatabaseCallback), null);` but what I have works, so am I doing something wrong here?

the other thing is that I believe in my callback I am supposed to call `EndInvoke()` as other stackoverflow questions state it is not optional. But then in other places it seems it is? But most comments I can find are from 2009 and I don't know if things have changed since then. Is this the only way to get the bool from the ExportDatabase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 new AsyncCallback(ExportDatabaseCallback)
```

is just the old, longer way to create a delegate. Your code does exactly the same.

And `EndInvoke()` is sometimes optional but you don't want to know when and when not. Just call it, and you're always right.

Comment: Many thanks for the response. It is all slowly falling into place. I guess as C# as evolved it has added shortcuts like this but examples don't always catch up.

Comment: Some people prefer the long form. Code generators too.

Comment: Well I guess it does make it totally clear what is happening and I can appreciate that some don't always like when stuff like that is done behind the scenes. It's useful to kno what is actually happening anyway.